# Shall I use mutable field in a Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, hibernate, spring-mvc

I use Spring Framework to develop a web application.

My DAO is a Spring bean. (using `@Component` annotation) This bean is used frequently: multiple users visit different pages, all using this DAO bean to query data.

In order to speed up query of frequently used data, I added a field in this DAO object: a map. So if one user queries one data set from DB, it is stored in this map, and next user querying the same data set can directly grab it from the map.

```
@Component
class MyDAO {
  private Map<T1, T2> cache = new HashMap<>();
  .....
}
```

My question: is it correct to declare a mutable field in Spring bean like this? My concern is: this field looks like a shared resource to me in multithread programs. And shared resource need proper synchronization. Does Spring takes care of synchronization or Spring prohibit such usage at all?

Answer (score 2):

No, spring does not take care of synchronization. You must make sure that your bean is thread safe. In this case it means access to the cache must be synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

spring wont do anything about concurrency in `singleton` scope,
you ca read a little about this topic at this:https://tarunsapra.wordpress.com/2011/08/21/spring-singleton-request-session-beans-and-thread-safety/